# Writing condition in MongoDB with "$and" and "$or"

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

What is the best mode for writing a condition in MongoDB like this:

```
field > 5 or (field = 5 and field2 > 3)
```

Is this?

```
$or: [ { field: { $gt: 5 } }, { $and: [ { field: { $eq: 5 } }, { field2: { $gt: 3 } } ] } ]
```

Or is there another better mode?

Answer (score 1):

Well there is no reason why it would not be, but since **all** MongoDB query arguments are already an "AND" condition unless stated specifically otherwise, it might as well just be:

```js
{ 
    "$or": [
        { "field": 5 },
        { 
           "field": { "$gt": 5 }
           "field2": { "$gt": 3 }
        }
    ]
}
```